# YII2 exists validator with filter

Tags: validation, yii2, exists

The rules for my model are shown below

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['default', 'boolean'],
        ['default', 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'default', 'filter' => ['default' => 1], 'message' => 'Cock'],
        ['length', 'integer'],
        ['length', 'unique'],
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to ensure that only a single record can have the model attribute 'default' set to 'true'. They can all be false, but no more than one can be set to true if that makes sense.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Class yii\validators\ExistValidator][1]

```
     public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['default', 'boolean'],
        ['default', 'exist', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\Where?SearchModel', 'targetAttribute' => 'default', 'filter' => ['default' => 1], 'message' => 'Cock'],
        ['length', 'integer'],
        ['length', 'unique'],
    ];
}
```

If ExistValidator can't help, you can try statement.

```
if (Model::find()->where((['default' => $model->default)->existes()){

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rafal, couldn't get the 'exists' validator to work. Really not sure if the 'exists' validator is the correct one. I created and inline validator to do the job. Thanks